# rounding text box results VB

Tags: vb.net

what is method on VB to round the results in a text box to three decimals, example 1.0030302 to 1.0003

Here is the code for the controlling button for the results..

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim resistivity As Double
    results.Show()
    resistivity = "1" / (Val(TextBox15.Text) + Val(TextBox30.Text) + Val(TextBox29.Text) + Val(TextBox28.Text) + Val(TextBox27.Text) + Val(TextBox26.Text) + Val(TextBox25.Text) + Val(TextBox24.Text) + Val(TextBox16.Text))
    results.Text = Convert.ToString(resistivity)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Decimal.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557.aspx) and [`Match.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dim resistivity As Decimal
Dim val1, val2, val3 As Decimal

If Decimal.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, val1) AndAlso Decimal.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, val2) AndAlso Decimal.TryParse(TextBox3.Text, val3) Then
    resistivity = Math.Round(1/ (val1 + val2 + val3), 4)
End If
```

Comment: hi thanks for response, it just gives the answer as 'results'

Comment: If you want to show the result in a `TextBox` just use `Decimal.ToString`: `results.Text = resistivity.ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

Strange question...

### Basic :

```
    results.Text = (Math.Round(resistivity * 1000) / 1000).ToString()
```

### What about writing "blabla" in TextBox15 ?

=> You're going to get an Exception if you don't check somewhere that all your Textboxes actually contains numbers... Just a remark ;)

Answer (score 0):

**First: Use Numeric-Controls**

Don't use Textboxes for Decimal-Values, that's a **really bad practise**.

Why would that be a bad practise?

- The user can type letters
- You need to validate the decimal yourself

**Second: Consider what you need**

Depending on what you need, there are three main math methods (examples included in links):

Round:

```
Math.Round(yourNumber,4)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k.aspx

Ceiling:

```
Math.Ceiling(yourNumber,4)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.ceiling.aspx

Floor:

```
Math.Floor(yourNumber,4)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a6a2sxy.aspx